# Where does the response get stored after a Dojo JSONP request?

Tags: dojo, jsonp, deferred

### JavaScript

For example, I have the following JavaScript code (Dojo 1.6 is already loaded):

```
dojo.require("dojo.io.script")

// PART I
var jsonpArgs = {
    url: "http://myapp.appspot.com/query",
    content: {
        id: "1234",
        name: "Juan",
        start_date: "2000-01-01",
        callback: "recover"
    }
};

// PART II
dojo.io.script.get(jsonpArgs).then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});

// PART III
function recover(data) {
    console.log(data);
}
```

### Direct query from browser

I understand that my server will receive the query as though I typed the following into the address bar:

```
http://myapp.appspot.com/query?id=1234&name=Juan&start_date=2000-01-01&callback=recover
```

### Expected response

If I directly queried my server using the browser address bar, I'll receive, in MIME type `application/json` and plaintext rendered in browser, something like this:

```
recover(
    {
        id: 1234,
        name: Juan,
        data: [
            ["2000-01-01", 1234],
            ["2000-01-02", 5678]
        ]
    }
);
```

### Problem

Now, looking back at Part II of the JavaScript, I'd execute the JSONP request with `dojo.io.script.get(jsonpArgs)`. This returns a `Deferred` object, which I can take advantage of by chaining `.then` after it. Note that I defined the handler for the `.then` event to output that captured `data` to the console.

However, all I get in the console is an `Event`. I tried to search its data tree, but I could not find the data I expected.

### Question

1. Where is the response for a JSONP request stored? How do I find it?
2. My server (which I control) only outputs a plaintext rendering of the data requested, wrapped in the `callback` function (here specified as `recover`), and specifies a `application/json` MIME type. Is there anything else I need to set up on my server, so that the response data is captured by the `Deferred` object?

### Attempted solution

I can actually recover the response by defining the callback function (in this case `recover` in Part III of the JavaScript). However, in the Dojo tutorials, they just recovered the data using the `Deferred` (and `.then`) framework. How do I do it using Dojo `Deferred`s?

### Update (using the Twitter example from Dojo tutorial)

Take for example this script from the Dojo tutorial, [Getting Jiggy With JSONP](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/jsonp/). I edited it to log data to the console.

```
dojo.require("dojo.io.script");
dojo.io.script.get({
    url: "http://search.twitter.com/search.json",
    callbackParamName: "callback",
    content: {q: "#dojo"}
}).then(function(data){
    //we're only interested in data.results, so strip it off and return it
    console.log(data); // I get an Object, not an Event, but no Twitter data when browsing the results property
    console.log(data.results) // I get an array of Objects
    return data.results;
});
```

For `console.log(data)`, I get an `Object`, not an `Event` as illustrated by my case. Since the example implies that the data resides in `data.results`, I also try to browse this tree, but I don't see my expected data from Twitter. I'm at a loss.

For `console.log(data.results)`, I get an array of `Object`s. If I query Twitter directly, this is what I'd get in plaintext. Each `Object` contains the usual tweet meta-data like username, time, user portrait, and the tweet itself. Easy enough.

This one hits me right on the head. The handler for the `.then` chain, an anonymous function, receives only one argument `data`. But why is it that the `results` property in `console.log(data)` **and** the returned object I get from `console.log(data.results)` are **different**?

Comment: Defining the callback is actually the way it works, as described in the chapter JSONP and dojo of this page : http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/ajax/. What other tutorial are you referring to ?

Comment: @Philippe, this is the tutorial I was referring to http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.6/jsonp/. It does explain defining the callback, but when I follow the Twitter example (even without defining a callback function), it just works. I fiddled around the `.then` chains, hooking it up to a handler `function(data)` such that it executes `console.log(data)`. I could actually browse the data tree and find the Twitter search results there.

Comment: Try to add the load function to your jsonpArgs. Put there what you currently have in your callback function.

Comment: @Philippe: Okay, I just added `load: recover` to jsonpArgs. It's defined as `function recover(data) {console.log(data);}`. I still get the same `Event` I mentioned before. What could be wrong?

Comment: @Philippe, I looked at the response headers for a direct-from-browser Twitter search query. I didn't find anything special, just the same `Content-Type: application/json` I give out from my app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I got it.

### Manual callback implementation

```
function recover(data) {
    console.log(data);
}

var jsonpArgs = {
    url: "http://myapp.appspot.com/query",
    content: {
        id: "1234",
        name: "Juan",
        start_date: "2000-01-01",
        callback: "recover"
};

dojo.io.script.get(jsonpArgs);
```

This is the request that my server will receive:

```
http://myapp.appspot.com/query?id=1234&name=Juan&start_date=2000-01-01&callback=recover
```

In this case, I'll expect the following output from my server:

```
recover({
    id: 1234,
    name: Juan,
    data: [
        ["2000-01-01", 1234],
        ["2000-01-02", 5678]
    ]
});
```

Three things to note:

1. Server will expect `callback` in the query URL string. `callback` is implemented as a property of `jsonpArgs`.
2. Because I specified `callback=recover`, my server will attach `recover(` + `the_data_I_need` + `)`, returns the whole string to the browser, and browser will execute `recover(the_data_I_need)`. This means...
3. That I'll have to define, for example, `function recover(one_argument_only) {doAnythingYouWantWith(one_argument_only)}`

The problem with this approach is that I cannot take advantage of `Deferred` chaining using `.then`. For example:

```
dojo.io.script.get(jsonpArgs).then(function(response_from_server) {
    console.log(response_from_server);
})
```

This will give me an `Event`, with no trace of the expected response at all.

---

### Taking advantage of Dojo's implementation of JSONP requests

```
var jsonpArgs = {
    url: "http://myapp.appspot.com/query",
    callbackParamName: "callback",
    content: {
        id: "1234",
        name: "Juan",
        start_date: "2000-01-01"
};

dojo.io.script.get(jsonpArgs);
```

This is the request that my server will receive:

```
http://myapp.appspot.com/query?id=1234&name=Juan&start_date=2000-01-01&callback=some_function_name_generated_by_dojo
```

In this case, I'll expect the following output from my server:

```
some_function_name_generated_by_dojo({
    id: 1234,
    name: Juan,
    data: [
        ["2000-01-01", 1234],
        ["2000-01-02", 5678]
    ]
});
```

Things to note:

1. Note the property of `jsonpArgs`, `callbackParamName`. The value of this property must be the name of the variable (in the query URL string) expected by the server. If my server expects `callbackfoo`, then `callbackParamName: "callbackfoo"`. In my case, my server expects the name `callback`, therefore `callbackParamName: "callback"`.
2. In the previous example, I specified in the query URL `callback=recover` and proceeded to implement `function recover(...) {...}`. This time, I do not need to worry about it. Dojo will insert its own preferred function `callback=some_function_name_generated_by_dojo`.
3. I imagine `some_function_name_generated_by_dojo` to be defined as:

Definition:

```
function some_function_name_generated_by_dojo(response_from_server) {
    return response_from_server;
}
```

Of course the definition is not that simple, but the advantage of this approach is that I can take advantage of Dojo's Deferred framework. See the code below, which is identical to the previous example:

```
dojo.io.script.get(jsonpArgs).then(function(response_from_server) {
    console.log(response_from_server);
})
```

This will give me the exact data I need:

```
{
    id: 1234,
    name: Juan,
    data: [
        ["2000-01-01", 1234],
        ["2000-01-02", 5678]
    ]
}
```

Comment: However, apparently the manual solution is the only option for certain services on the web. For example, if I let dojo generate his own jsonp method name I get something like this url http://json-lipsum.appspot.com/?what=paras&start=yes&amount=10&lang=en&callback=dojo.io.script.jsonp_dojoIoScript1._jsonpCallback. This particular service does not like the dots in the callback name and returns a raw json (try it and then replace the callback param with a name without dots to see what I mean...